# modx revolution permission "create directory in context-menu"

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I want a usergroup to have the possibility to add a new directory in the file-tree by rightclicking with the mouse on an existing folder.

I have managed to add the icons in the manager tree but I can't find out which permission is needed to show this option in the menu that opens on a rightclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, just found it out. I was looking intot the wrong permission set. I needet to select some more permissions in the "Media Source User" set, which is responsible for the Mediasource I have enabled for the usergroup I wanted to change the permissions for.

But Thanks for everyone that has read this Question so far! :)